# Extended error handling - skip specific errors during the script execution

Tags: postgresql

Postgres allows to handle a lot of cases when object already exists or does not exist which really helps to write re-runnable scirpts.

I mean commands like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`, `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS ...` as well as `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ...`, `ALTER TABLE ... DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS ...`, etc.

So when `exists` clause is used Postgres shows notice instead of an error.

```
postgres=# drop table nothing;
ERROR:  table "nothing" does not exist
postgres=#
```

vs

```
postgres=# drop table if exists nothing;
NOTICE:  table "nothing" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
postgres=#
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to ignore specific errors during script execution. Maybe it is possible to set some flag instructing Postgres to ignore specific codes.

So that even for below statement it would return notice instead of an error when role does not exist.

```
postgres=# create table g(g int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# grant select on g to noone;
ERROR:  role "noone" does not exist
postgres=#
```

This is just one example. In general I would like to be able to continue with the execution without errors because those errors are "normal situation" (only for specific error codes, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the script in an anonymous block and then enclose each statement to be protected in BEGIN/EXCEPTION/END. For example, the following:

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql
$BLOCK$
  BEGIN
    BEGIN
      CREATE TABLE test_table
      (
        id integer
      );
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN duplicate_table THEN
        RAISE NOTICE '[%] [%] %, skipping', LOCALTIMESTAMP(0), SQLSTATE, sqlerrm;
END;
  END
$BLOCK$;
```

behaves similarly to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id integer);`. The list of error codes and their corresponding symbolic condition names can be found in [Appendix A. PostgreSQL Error Codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/errcodes-appendix.html).

If one prefers not to wrap each statement in a separate BEGIN/EXCEPTION/END, then the following approach could be used:

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql
$BLOCK$
  DECLARE
    rec record;
  BEGIN
    FOR rec IN
      SELECT *
        FROM (VALUES ('DROP TABLE test_table'),
                     ('CREATE TABLE test_table(id integer)'),
                     ('CREATE TABLE test_syntax_error'),
                     ('ALTER TABLE test_table ADD id integer')) script(statement)
      LOOP
        BEGIN
          EXECUTE rec.statement;
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN syntax_error OR undefined_table THEN
            RAISE NOTICE '[%] [%] %, skipping', LOCALTIMESTAMP(0), SQLSTATE, sqlerrm;
        END;
      END LOOP;
  END;
$BLOCK$;
```

If test_table doesn't exist, then running the above results in:

```
[2023-03-06 16:50:26] [42701] ERROR: column "id" of relation "test_table" already exists
[2023-03-06 16:50:26] Where: SQL statement "ALTER TABLE test_table ADD id integer"
[2023-03-06 16:50:26] PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 13 at EXECUTE
[2023-03-06 21:50:27] [42P01] table "test_table" does not exist, skipping
[2023-03-06 21:50:27] [42601] syntax error at end of input, skipping
```

Note that the fatal exception is reported prior to the notices.

Comment: With such approach I need to wrap every single DDL statement if I want to skip errors for it. The goal is to ignore those errors without wrappers and extra coding.

Comment: If you are unwilling to write the wrapping block for each DDL then you **cannot** do what you want. When an error occurs plpgsql always goes immediately to the exception section for that block or if none to the exception section for the containing block, continuing to the highest or if no exception block found throwing the error to the external caller and exiting the entire routine. The only way to isolate individual statements is to wrap the individual statements.